# How to fix cur error: could not resolve host error

Tags: python, curl, server, socketserver

I'm learning networks (socket lib in python) and have a problem. When I make a request to this app answer on this request is an error: "Could not resolve host: POST"

Here is my code

```
    import socket

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('',9091))
    
    print("DATABASE INITED")
    while True:
        sock.listen(1)
        connection, address = sock.accept()
        buf = connection.recv(64)
        if len(buf) > 0:
            print(buf)
            conn.send(buf.upper())
    
    conn.close()
```

And here is code to curl request

```
curl -d "data = 'example'" POST 127.0.0.1:9091
```

Query and program located on the one Linux computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl --data "data = 'example'" 127.0.0.1:9091
```